# ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden when trying to upload video

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to upload a video to Vimeo from my account's S3 bucket and I am getting an error:

`[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

I have set up the CloudFormation stack using the SAM cli.  After googling it seems that perhaps my policy doesn't have enough permissions, but I am not sure how I would designate the permission set in the YAML file.

Here is the relevant code and error
**CODE**

```
                # Get the URI for the S3 Bucket
                s3_bucket = rec["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
                s3 = boto3.client("s3")

                with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as file_obj:
                    s3.download_fileobj(s3_bucket, s3_key, file_obj)
                    vimeo_replace_file(vimeo_id, file_obj)
```

**ERROR**

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 61, in lambda_handler
    s3.download_fileobj(s3_bucket, s3_key, file_obj)
  File "/var/task/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 795, in download_fileobj
    return future.result()
  File "/var/task/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/var/task/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/var/task/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 269, in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/s3transfer/download.py", line 354, in _submit
    response = client.head_object(
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 915, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/app.py", line 61, in lambda_handler     s3.download_fileobj(s3_bucket, s3_key, file_obj)   File "/var/task/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 795, in download_fileobj     return future.result()   File "/var/task/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result     return self._coordinator.result()   File "/var/task/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result     raise self._exception   File "/var/task/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 269, in _main     self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)   File "/var/task/s3transfer/download.py", line 354, in _submit     response = client.head_object(   File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 915, in _make_api_call     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

**Template.YAML**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  vimeo-replace-file
  Sample SAM Template for vimeo-replace-file
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60

Resources:
  VimeoReplaceFile:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: core/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      MemorySize: 6114
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref SrcBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*

  SrcBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  VimeoReplaceFileFunction:
    Description: "VimeoReplaceFile Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt VimeoReplaceFile.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, if this will help anyone.  Basically, I needed to add that policy into the YAML file.

So, the policy is:

```
Policies:
        - AmazonS3FullAccess
```

**Template.YAML**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  vimeo-replace-file
  Sample SAM Template for vimeo-replace-file
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60

Resources:
  VimeoReplaceFile:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: core/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      MemorySize: 6114
        - x86_64
      Policies:
        - AmazonS3FullAccess
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref SrcBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*


  SrcBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

Outputs:
  VimeoReplaceFileFunction:
    Description: "VimeoReplaceFile Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt VimeoReplaceFile.Arn
```